# How can I pin Backup and Restore to the start menu?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, windows-7-backup, pin

I want to pin Backup and Restore to the start menu since I use it so much, but it appears to be impossible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me.  The accepted answer makes even less sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the right click context menu option is gone to pin that program, but you can click & drag it, first down to the "back" option at the bottom of the start menu, then up into the "pinned" area for a workaround.

Comment: Sweet!  It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu\` and create a shortcut there.

You can do that either by dragging `Backup and Restore` from the Control Panel or by creating a new shortcut to the command `%WINDIR%\explorer.exe shell:::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{B98A2BEA-7D42-4558-8BD1-832F41BAC6FD}`.